# Is there a pressure check valve that doesn't bleed the excess pressure?

Tags: pressure, valves

My issue is that downstream, I have a boiler making pressure at 10.54 bar and upstream I have a system that must NOT be heated at any point beyond 130 °C. My plan is to make sure the system pressure upstream stays 3 bar at max and doesn't fall significantly below that as long as the pressure downstream is greater than 3 bar but I can't use any relief valves or anything as they bleed away too much steam. Is there a check valve or any other valve systems that will make sure that the pressure stays less than 3 bar at all times and preferable, more than 2 bar as well? Please don't recommend any electronic systems.

Comment: Use a pressure regulator.

Comment: That would require too much human input in case the boiler pressure fluctuates. I need a system that opens the valve when pressure drops below 2 kg and closes the valve as soon as it goes above 3kg and just heats the system from 2-3 kgs of steam.

Comment: Human input? What do you think a pressure regulator does exactly? Also, you seem to be using the terms "downstream" and "upstream" backwards. Rivers begin upstream and flow in the downstream direction.

Comment: Okay so they operate constantly they just need excess pressure on inlet side. Kinda what I was looking for so this will work. Thanks

Comment: Yeah..................

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but if pressure systems are outside your area of expertise (and it seems like they are), I'd strongly advise getting the design approved by a licensed expert.  Steam and pressure systems can be very dangerous, and many safety incidents occur when systems are designed or operated by people who do not have the requisite knowledge.

Comment: You don't even know what I discovered and what my problem is so I am going to take your disrespect as ignorance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a pressure regulator or pressure reducing valve.

They work by mechanically actuating a valve based on the outlet pressure (the one you want to keep at 3 bar), choking off the flow when it rises.